# MySQL duplicate entry detection on big joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a sql statement that looks like the following. I am trying to select all the entries that have duplicates and then display each duplicate entry.

Let say the resulting data of a basic select has

```
1 green michigan column4 column5 column6
3 orange michigan column4 column5 column6
11 purple florida column4 column5 column6
14 pink arizona column4 column5 column6
15 purple texas column4 column5 column6
20 orange california column4 column5 column6
```

the result im trying to get is

```
20 orange california column4 column5 column6
3 orange michigan column4 column5 column6
11 purple florida column4 column5 column6
15 purple texas column4 column5 column6
```

I added this to the end of my select statement

```
GROUP BY join4.color
HAVING count(join4.color) > 2
```

However i'm only getting

```
3 orange michigan column4 column5 column6
15 purple texas column4 column5 column6
```

The main select looks like this

```
SELECT
    join1.id,
    join4.color,
    join2.state,
    table1.column4,
    join5.column5,
    table1.column6
FROM
    table1
JOIN 1
LEFT JOIN 2
LEFT JOIN 3
LEFT JOIN 4
LEFT JOIN 5
WHERE
    table1.active = 1
AND
    table1.valid = 1
ORDER BY table1.column4 DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do it but you can use the results you got from the 'GROUP BY' statement to pull only the rows that have a color that is in your 'GROUP BY' statement.

So use it as a subquery...

```
SELECT
    join1.id,
    join4.color,
    join2.state,
    table1.column4,
    join5.column5,
    table1.column6
FROM
    table1
JOIN 1
LEFT JOIN 2
LEFT JOIN 3
LEFT JOIN 4
LEFT JOIN 5
WHERE
    table1.active = 1
AND
    table1.valid = 1
AND
    join4.Color IN (SELECT Color
                    FROM JOIN4
                    GROUP BY join4.color
                    HAVING count(join4.color) > 2)
ORDER BY table1.column4 DESC
```

Comment: i did a subquery on a simplified version of itself inside the IN and it worked, thanks!